# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keybord'

Tags: python-3.x, module, keyboard

I am using python 3.x. I have installed `pip` and I actually made a path to `\Scripts` in windows. Then I installed module named [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). However when I try to import it to my project I get error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keybord'`. I have read some others answers with problems like this but I couldn't find right answer.

Comment: How did you install `keyboard`? Are you perhaps using a venv? Does importing keyboard work from the CLI?

Comment: I have installed it from CLI, I can even see that installed module in site-packages folder. Yea, I was using venv, unfortunately after changing to pipenv its still not working.

Comment: If you are using a venv, you need to install it under the venv.

Comment: I am sorry, and I guess it is easy, but could you tell me how to please?

Comment: Run the `activate.bat` in your command prompt. From here, using `where pip` should point towards your venv and not your global python installation. After that, anything you install using `pip install` should install to your venv.

Answer (score 0):

just install keyboard and that will solve your problem.

```
pip install keyboard
```